# REST Web Service - Different Types for Get and Create

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

With ASP.Net Web Api, is it ok / good practice for your GET endpoint to return a different type than your POST endpoint accepts?

In many cases, fields we want to return in a GET cannot be set in a POST, such as "LastUpdated", "Total", etc, necessitating different types?

Example, GET returns ReservationForGetModel, while POST accepts a ReservationForCreateModel:

```
public class ReservationController : ApiController {
...

  public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) {
    Reservation reservation = _reservationService.Get(id);
    //map Reservation to ReservationForGetModel
    //return ReservationForGetModel
  }

  public HttpResponseMessage Post(ReservationForCreateModel reservation) {
    //create reservation using ReservationForCreateModel here
    //return 201 with location header set
  }

}
```

Comment: You can use the DTO pattern for GET request, there's nothing wrong with it!

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable to me - your example describes a very good reason to have different types.

Comment: A note - you can strongly-type your return values - they don't need to be `HttpResponseMessage` - for example, your GET can be `public ReservationForGetModel Get(int id) { }`

Comment: @JoeEnos yes thanks, but sometimes you need to alter headers etc.  Ideally, you can return strong types from your actions and then handle headers etc in action filters / handlers, but that's another post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GET and POST can use completely different media types.  Consider HTML forms:  you POST with `application/x-www-urlencoded-form` and GET returns `text/html`.

With GET and PUT it is more likely that the media-types are symmetric, however, that is not a hard rule.

Comment: Sure they *can*, but I wouldn't say it's RESTful.  REST is about creating and getting resources and a resource has one representation.

Comment: @bryanmac Can you provide a reference for that statement? My understanding is that a resource can have many different representations. What REST constraint do you see being violated?

Comment: It can but when it returns different representations it's because of the content type header is different or querystring params differ.  For cacheability, requesting a resource by the same url should return the same representation - so the url becomes the identifier for that representation of the resource and the verb denotes what you are doing with that representation of the resource.  I wouldn't call posting a form RESTful - posting that representation as a POST with the resource in the body is more RESTful IMHO.

Comment: That allows for symmetry and it allows you to document this is the shape of this resource (whether it's formatting is JSON, xml, etc...).  That allows me to create a resource by that shape, POST it to create it, GET it, modify it and PUT the same shape to update it.

Comment: And as with all these REST discussions, there's no hard and fast rules - but for the reasons above this is what our public APIs do and what is common in other RESTful designs I've come across.

Comment: @bryanmac The vary header is designed specifically to allow caches to disambiguate between different representations for the same URI.  Unfortunately the vary header is pretty much broken with the Wininet proxy cache.

Comment: @bryanmac The term REST is so brutally abused these days, extracting guidance from "common RESTful designs" is very misleading.  You have to go back to the core REST constraints and identify what are the negative consequences of choosing a particular path.  Allowing representation symmetry for GET/PUT is developer friendly but is in no way required to achieve the benefits of a RESTful system.

Comment: @bryanmac There are hard and fast rules in REST, they just are not the prescriptive rules most people are looking for.  You mention that "symmetry ... allows you to document ... the shape of the resource".  The media-type/link relation should be doing this.  I guess you are limiting yourself to `application/json` and `application/xml` which severely limits you in the way you can describe the representation.

Comment: @bryanmac and one more thing you mentioned about query parameters.  Different query parameters make a different URI and therefore a different resource.

Comment: @bryanmac with your APIs, what do you do with calculated fields? This is the crux of my issue with "representation symmetry"

Comment: @bryanmac Consider the usage of PUT.  If symmetry were required with calculated fields then the client would be required to calculate the values and the server forced to accept those values! Which makes no sense.

Comment: The resource has a shape/schema - some are writeable, some are read-only/calculated.  When you POST, PUT, PATCH, it's not valid to set a read only field.  They still share the same shape.

Comment: As I said, this isn't a hard and fast "REST rule" - it's a more RESTful API and having an *API* that takes a form is catering to the web page form specific use case and not the RESTful concept of POSTing a RESTful resource as an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but probably shouldn't.  Web API is designed as a platform for RESTful APIs, and that includes

```
Manipulation of resources through these representations
```

Let's say I have a mobile app consuming your webservice.  To create an entity, I first make a ReservationForCreateModel, and POST it.  Now I want to update it.  I have to have client side code that can convert a ReservationForCreateModel to a ReservationModel, which will be a repetition of the same code on the server.

Use a DTO pattern, and send back the same type of object you take in.  Perhaps internally to the server they'll be split, but to the outside world there should be a common language.

It sounds like your real issue is this

> In many cases, fields we want to return in a GET cannot be set in a POST, such as "LastUpdated", "Total", etc, necessitating different types?

Why can't you set these values?

Comment: "Why can't you set these values" - because they're calculated fields, the client cannot manipulate them.  However, we want the the client to be able to see these fields on a GET.

Comment: It is very hard to use DTOs and not violate the self-descriptive REST constraint.  Usually it requires out-of-band knowledge to deal with DTOs.

Comment: +1 - agreed that you can ... and not even to say you shouldn't, that is unless you're trying to be restful which the title is asking about :)  So, if RESTful, then you shouldn't.

Comment: So, how should I handle calculated fields?

Comment: @JoshNoe: The resource still has the same shape - on a POST, PUT, PATCH, they are not set.  So, you document the shape of your resource, you POST that resource (don't set readonly/calculated).  You get that same resource.  Then you can update a single field and PUT it back.  A RESTful resource identified by an URL/params/content type has a representation.  Sure you can have others by different URLS/params/content type.

Comment: So the issue is that you want the object to have fields which, when created on the client with deserialization, can be written to, but afterwards are readonly to logic it seems.  There's several strategies you can use to do this (reflection/serialization attributes, custom serializers, or translator objects).  You might want to revisit your design though - do these fields belong with that object then, if they have different behavior on both sides?